# Apply regex on matched substring

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have few thousands of text lines like this:

```
go to <CITY>rome</CITY> <COUNTRY>italy</COUNTRY>
```

My desired output is to replace everything from the first tagged word (rome) to the last one (italy) and put  tag:

```
go to <ADDRESS>rome italy</ADDRESS>
```

I can match the portion of the text line which is tagged with:

```
<.*>
```

This will greedily select all text from first < to last >. I would like then the tags removed and put `<ADDRESS>` and `</ADDRESS>` around the matched portion.

The possible tags are: `<STREETNUM>`, `<STREET>`, `<CITY>`, `<STATE>`, `<ZIP>` and `<COUNTRY>`. Any subset of these tags can appear and in any order. The tags are never nested.

I have searched SO and googled to no avail. Perhaps I can use a named capturing group and then apply search/replace regex on it but I don't know how. Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sed` line will do it:

```bash
sed 's/<CITY>\(.*\)<\/CITY>.*<COUNTRY>\(.*\)<\/COUNTRY>/<ADDRESS>\1 \2<\/ADDRESS> /g'
```

For example:

```
sed 's/<CITY>\(.*\)<\/CITY>.*<COUNTRY>\(.*\)<\/COUNTRY>/<ADDRESS>\1 \2<\/ADDRESS> /g'  <<< "go to <CITY>rome</CITY> <COUNTRY>italy</COUNTRY>"
```

It prints:

```
go to <ADDRESS>rome italy</ADDRESS>
```

It basically captures what is inside the `CITY` tag and inside the `COUNTRY` tag and then replace them with the captured groups values enclose the `ADDRESS` tag

---

If you're using Linux, you can avoid escaping `(` using the `-E` flag:

```bash
sed -E 's/<CITY>(.*)<\/CITY>.*<COUNTRY>(.*)<\/COUNTRY>/<ADDRESS>\1 \2<\/ADDRESS> /g'
```

---

**UPDATE:**

To achieve the expected result you could use several commands in the following order of operation:

1. Remove the `go to` text: `sed 's/go to //g'`
2. Remove all the tag characters: `tr -d '</>'`
3. Once all tag chars are removed, you can safely delete the words `STREETNUM`, `STREET`, `CITY`, `STATE`, `ZIP` and `COUNTRY` from the input:

   `sed -E 's/CITY|COUNTRY|STATE|ZIP|STREETNUM|STREET//g'`
4. Take the output generated from the previous commands concatenation and output it inside the `<ADDRESS></ADDRESS>` tags:

   `xargs -i echo "go to <ADDRESS>{}</ADDRESS>"`

The final command is the following, here `$LINE` should contain the line to process:

```
sed 's/go to //g' <<< "$LINE" | tr -d '</>' | sed -E 's/CITY|COUNTRY|STATE|ZIP|STREETNUM|STREET//g' | xargs -i echo "go to <ADDRESS>{}</ADDRESS>"
```

An example:

Running:

```
sed 's/go to //g' <<< "go to <STATE>Bolivar</STATE> <COUNTRY>Venezuela</COUNTRY> <STREETNUM>5</STREETNUM> " | tr -d '</>' | sed -E 's/CITY|COUNTRY|STATE|ZIP|STREETNUM|STREET//g' | xargs -i echo "go to <ADDRESS>{}</ADDRESS>"
```

Will print:

```
go to <ADDRESS>Bolivar Venezuela 5 </ADDRESS>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. However, your regex assumes that first is the CITY which is then followed by COUNTRY. This is not always the case, any sequence and subset of tags is possible. I updated my question with this info.

Comment: Yeah, that is because the original question didn't state those tags

Comment: Yes, you are right and I apologize for not being precise. Point taken.